# jqgrid link to modal dialog of another grid

Tags: jqgrid

I try to implement the link from one grid to the modal dialog of another grid. I made an  [example](http://babiychuk.com/demo/en/catalog/index/c_picture)
to illustrate this problem. If you choose in a context menu (right mouseclick) of each row of the picture grid, you will find some Actions. One of them is "Go to scan info". Here I would like to have a link to modal dialog of grid "Scans" and modal dialog should put the user depending whether the scan record for the selected picture allready exist or not, to the Add/Edit modal dialog.

Does anybody already implemented something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us we have two grids on one page: one with id="grid" and another with id="scan". Exactly like you call `jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow',id)` on double-click on the first grid you can call `jQuery('#scan').jqGrid('editGridRow',id)` in the context menu "Go to scan info". The only thing which you have to know is to know the ids on the second grid. Before calling of `jQuery('#scan').jqGrid('editGridRow',id)` you can impelemt any additional logic (like testing whether "the scan record for the selected picture allready exist or not").

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you need insert another jqgrid into modal dialog. Did you try to insert jqgrid function into [open event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-open) of jquery [dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-open)?

You have to call jqgrid function on demand, not in document.ready statement in this case.

Imo this could work (not tested yet):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) {

     $("#grid").jqGrid({ 
       ... all of options...
     });

   }
});
```